# Help solving Differential Equation with Boundary Conditions (Genetics)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

The following is a cline where to the left of the center, one allele is favored and the other is disfavored while on the right the opposite pattern holds.

[Figure showing relationship between location and allele favored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6hCu.png)

This equation is the equilibrium spatial distribution of allele frequencies.

$s\gamma(x)q(x)(1-q(x))=-(\sigma^2/2)(d^2q(x)/dx^2)$

where $\gamma(x)=1$ for $x<0$ and $\gamma(x)=-1$ for $x\geq0$

How would one solve the above equilibrium equation with the following boundary conditions to get the appropriate functional form of the cline?

$q(-\infty) = 1$ and $q(\infty) = 0$

The authors note that "by dividing the distance x by ℓ = σ/√s, we can remove the effect of our parameters from the above equation. This compound parameter ℓ is the characteristic length of our cline, and it is this parameter which determines over what geographic scale we change from allele 2 predominating to allele 1 predominating as we move across our environmental shift."

Can someone help me 1) derive the functional form and help me interpret ℓ in the context of the figure. The example comes from https://github.com/cooplab/popgen-notes/releases/download/v1.2/minicoop.pdf page 232.

Comment: Please add your equations in LateX (use dollar signs) and not external links.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just added them.